# Does VB.Net 2003 support System.Collections.Generic?

Tags: vb.net, reference

I am planning to use a List in my application but when I was searching for System.Collections.Generic, it only has System.Collections. I tried to look it up in the "add reference" and its not there.

Could anybody tell me where I can add the reference for this.

Thanks for those who can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. 2003 works with .net 1.1 and Generics were introduced in 2.0. You'll need Visual Studio 2005 or later.

Answer (score 2):

Generics were introducted  in .Net 2 . So if you work with .Net 2 or later it's supported

Comment: What visual studio do you use ? Have you tried to install .Net 2 framework ?

Comment: 2003 sir, trying to install .net framework 2 but i can find a site where to download it