# workaround to VB.Net 2003 System.Collections.Generic?

Tags: vb.net, .net-1.1

I'm working in an old web application (vb.net 2003) and I'm trying to use a generic list of a custom class.

I realized that System.Collections.Generic was introduced in .Net 2 according to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497790/does-vb-net-2003-support-system-collections-generic)

Is there any alternative to the list? For instance an array of class?

Let's say I have the following class definition:

```
Public Class Box
  Public x As Integer
  Public y As Integer
End Class
```

And an array of Class Box:

```
Dim BoxList() As Box
BoxList(0).x = 1
BoxList(0).y = 1

BoxList(1).x = 2
BoxList(2).y = 2
```

But I'm getting an error when `BoxList(0).x = 1` error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

I'm just guessing here.

Comment: Did you fill the array? Is there an instanze of Box in BoxList(0)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ArrayList`, like this:

```
Dim BoxList As New ArrayList
Dim box = New Box()
box.x = 1
box.y = 2
BoxList.Add(box)
```

Note: It is recommended that you add a constructor to the `Box` class that will accept the `x` and `y` values, like this:

```
Public Class Box
    Public x As Integer
    Public y As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal _x As Integer, ByVal _y As Integer)
        x = _x
        y = _y
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now you can shorten your `ArrayList` code to this:

```
Dim BoxList As New ArrayList
BoxList.Add(New Box(1, 2))
```

To use the values in the `ArrayList` you will need to un-box (pun not intended) the value out of the `ArrayList`, like this:

```
For Each box In BoxList
    ' Use x value, like this
    CType(box, Box).x
Next
```

OR (as Meta-Knight suggested)

```
For Each box As Box In BoxList
    ' Now box is typed as Box and not object, so just use it
    box.x
Next
```

Comment: that worked awesome! thank you! 4 mins to accept your answer :)

Comment: ...or even better, use auto-unboxing feature of ForEach (For Each box As Box In BoxList)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom collection class - this is what we had to do back before generics. [This article from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xth2y6ft%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) gives you the specifics:

```
''' Code copied directly from article
Public Class WidgetCollection
   Inherits System.Collections.CollectionBase

    Public Sub Add(ByVal awidget As Widget)
       List.Add(aWidget)
    End Sub
    Public Sub Remove(ByVal index as Integer)
       If index > Count - 1 Or index < 0 Then
          System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Index not valid!")
       Else
          List.RemoveAt(index)
       End If
    End Sub
    Public ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal index as Integer) As Widget
       Get
          Return CType(List.Item(index), Widget)
       End Get
    End Property

End Class
```